# Invalid syntax in Python when calling variable

Tags: python, variables, syntax

I'm trying to make the code display Grade B and Grade C when I am giving it a certain exam score and attendance. However, it isn't doing this. The Grade A bit is perfect though. It's coming up with an invalid syntax error for examscore, although I've used the same 'syntax' on the two lines above it and it's not working. I'm only new to Python and this is one of my first projects.

```
examscore = int(input(("Enter exam score: ")))
attendance = int(input(("Enter attendance: ")))

if examscore >90 and attendance >90:
     print("Grade A")

elif examscore >80 or <=90 and attendance >90:
     print("Grade B")

elif examscore >70 or <=80 and attendance >90:
     print("Grade C")
```

This is the error I got.

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the error you are getting

Comment: Just done this now. Hope it is clearer.

Comment: `examscore >80 or <=90 ` does not do what you expect it to

Comment: When posting error messages, please post the *full* error message, including the stack trace.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to check the upper range at all since it is always covered by previous checks and you're using `elif`.

```
examscore = int(input(("Enter exam score: ")))
attendance = int(input(("Enter attendance: ")))

if examscore >90 and attendance >90:
     print("Grade A")

elif examscore >80 and attendance >90:
     print("Grade B")

elif examscore >70 and attendance >90:
     print("Grade C")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
elif examscore >80 or examscore <= 90 and attendance >90:
```

instead of:

```
elif examscore >80 or <= 90 and attendance >90:
```

Comment: Incorrect. For example, `examscore == 75` and `attendance > 90` will report `Grade B`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write `elif examscore >80 or <=90`, the correct syntax is `elif examscore >80 <=10`

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax error is due to invalid `or` condition. `<=` expects variables on both sides.

```
elif examscore >80 or <=90 and attendance >90:  # Error here
     print("Grade B")

elif examscore >70 or <=80 and attendance >90:  # Here as well
     print("Grade C")
```

You can fix this by using

```
elif 80 < examscore <= 90 and attendence > 90:
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems.

First off:

```
examscore >80 or <=90 and attendance >90
```

is not valid syntax.  Think of it as `[examscore > 80] OR [ <= 90 ] AND [attendance > 90]`.  I think you'll see that `[ <= 90 ]` is not something that can be evaluated.  Instead, it should say `[examscore <= 90 ]`.

Secondly, different languages follow different rules in how they "bind" AND and OR conditions.  Without parentheses, it's hard to determine how you intend for this logic to be evaluated.  I'm *guessing* that what you're hoping for is:

```
    examscore > 80 or (examscore <=90 and attendance > 90)
```

meaning that anyone who scored over 80 or less than 90 but had an attendance of greater than 90, gets a "B" (which is a funny metric for getting a B -- they could score 0, and as long as they where in class, they get "B"? -- but that's not relevant to your question).  Without the parens, it's hard to be sure.

Comment: I doubt this is what was intended. I think it should've been `and` instead of `or`.